# WPF Binding on specific index of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am working on a specific UI which shows me some data. In my VM, I have an array Data[] of n elements, where n is known (typically, n=10).
To display my data, I use converters which have a high complexity, which I can't modify.
Due to this complexity, I don't want to display all the elements at the same time. So I have a method in my VM which fires:

```
PropertyChanged(this, "Data[" + i + "]");
```

where the value of i is chosen by the method itself.

In my view, I have 10 controls with binding to each of the Data[i] (0 <= i <= 9).

However, this does not seem to work. Any idea of how I can update the binding on 1 precise element of the array and not by updating the whole data?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, just use the proper tool for the job. Create a custom class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to hold your data with separate properties, rather than using an array as if it were 1980.

Comment: Sheridan is right, it would be best if your `Data[X]` array contained objects that implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and then you could raise your change notification using something like `Data[i].RaisePropertyChanged()`. Is there any specific reason you're trying to do it this way instead?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Indeed there are some reasons not to do so: I have some treatment on my data which gives me a table of the indexes to modify. I assume I can find a way to avoid this index array.

Comment: I think you should make 10 bindable variables to your 10 controls and raise them after changes. Don't Forget to make also changes in your array. It is not nice, but it may help you, if you don't want to use INotifyPropertyChanged for each of your properties(I prefer this way)

Comment: Ok I just had a look and the solution using INotifyPropertyChanged in a special data object works well!

Comment: But "Data[" + i + "]" is not a property.   Create 10 properties.